# Code fails only if not logged in

Tags: views

Hello I'm currently working in the template.php file to preprocess a view and i'm experiencing strange things:

This relates to a field collection field:

```
  $collect_field = $value->field_field_screenshot[0]['rendered']['entity'];
```

Without being logged in this code fails with

> Notice: Undefined index: entity

If logged in everything is fine...

Somebody could imagine what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, no such index `'entity'` exists in the array `$value->field_field_screenshot[0]['rendered']` Do a `dpm($value->field_field_screenshot[0]['rendered'])` when both logged in and logged out and you will see the difference.

Is `field_screenshot` associated with a user account or profile? In which case, the anonymous user object has no such field, so you're trying to assign to `$collect_field` something that doesn't exist. You should assert whether the user is logged in or not before doing the assignment.

Comment: One thing to add, if you want to do a dpm when logged out you need to grant anonymous users permission to view devel data.